# make maximize view for oracle 10g form in Netscape browser

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

When I run a form in Oracle 10g, the form in Netscape appears very small.
How can I make a form in Netscape browser maximized?

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]. Try to provide us with what you tried so that we can assist further

Comment: How do you call, from an `application server` remotely or from `Forms Builder` locally ?

Comment: is it the sandbox that is too small or the form itself?

Comment: Wow, I remember Netscape. It hasn't existed for 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try with

```
SET_WINDOW_PROPERTY(forms_mdi_window, window_state, maximize);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want to call runtime from design time of Forms Builder by meaning to run form in Oracle 10g. Even if you set your `MDI Window`'s state to maximum, you won't be able to have a big display area in the browser unless your `formsweb.cfg`( search at your `%MV_HOME%` for its location ) file's width and height parameters are small in `formsweb.cfg`  file.

Search for `formsweb.cfg` in your Middleware home and change these parameters to the values below:

```
# Forms applet parameter
width=1200 --> from 750(as default)
# Forms applet parameter
height=900 --> from 600(as default)
```

During this edit, `Admin Server For Weblogic Server Domain` shouldn't be running. After completing this edit, rerun from `startWebLogic.cmd` and see the Display portion in the browser is enlarged.